# How does socket error code "sckOpCanceled 1004" occured by in windows?

Tags: windows, sockets, vb6, winsock

Recently I'm reading an old project source written by vb6. Someone told me this error code means that remote socket client sent a "Cancel" singnal.As far as I know,there is no "Cancel" action in socket methods.
I think this error code just means socket was cancelled by system for some reason but not by remote.

I can only find this word in a few documents interpreted as "The operation was canceled".
And I want to know how can I occur this error programmatically (any language is ok)